# Is possible to save cython type in variable?

Tags: python, cython

I have a class (imported from a `.h` file) that uses a template in my `pxd` file like this:

```py
# Number.pxd

cdef extern from "myHeader.h":
    cdef cppclass Number[T]
        Number()
        ...
```

What I want to do is to initialize a class instance with a cython type depending on the user input, for example:

```py
# pyx file
from Number cimport Number

# User passes 'dtype' as argument
def func(dtype):

    cdef Number[int] n
    
    if dtype == "int":
        n = Number[int]()
    elif dtype == "float":
        n = Number[float]()
    elif ... # etc
```

My question is if there is an elegant way of doing this without writing an `if` for each type, something like saving a type into a dictionary (I know is not possible) and then call it like this:

```py
n = Number[ dict_types[dtype] ]()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cython relies on static typing to do its thing. This would not be static.

Comment: Right.  In regular Python, you certainly CAN store types in a dictionary like that; your proposed code would work fine.  Not in Cython.

Comment: @TimRoberts So I don't have another option more than do an `if` for each type

Comment: Even that elif chain isn't going to do what you want. `n` is declared as `Number[int]`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica yeah I know, that's another issue I'm trying to solve. I tried to use a fused type but it seems that they are not allowed as a template type `cdef Number[fusedType] n`